# Number of nontrivial solutions to equations of given genus (Ruzsa)

Tags: co.combinatorics, additive-combinatorics

I am working on Ruzsa's paper "Solving a linear equation in a set of integers I," which is here: http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/aa/aa65/aa6537.pdf.

Consider a linear equation $a_1x_1+\dots+a_kx_k=0$.

Define its to be the largest number $m$ such that we can partition the set $\{1,\dots,k\}$ as $\mathcal T_1\cup\dots\cup\mathcal T_m$, where the $\mathcal T_j$'s are disjoint nonempty sets satisfying $\sum_{i\in\mathcal T_j}a_i=0$. We define $r(N)$ to be $$r(N)=\max\{|\mathcal A|:\mathcal A\subseteq[1,N]\},$$ where $\mathcal A$ dos not admit a trivial solution to the equation.

In Theorem 3.6, the author says that any equation of genus $m$ has $r(N)\ll N^{1/m}$.

To do this, he constructs an auxiliary symmetric equation with $2m$ variables. Any solution to this equation is a solution to the original one and, in fact, every nontrivial solution to this equation is a nontrivial solution to the original one. In a previous theorem (namely, Theorem 3.2), he showed that the auxiliary equation has $O(N^{1/m})$ nontrivial solutions. Then he concludes that this theorem implies the result.

I understand everything in his proof, up to the very last sentence. The way I understood things, it seems to be that the original equation actually has *more* solutions than the auxiliary equation, so coming up with an upper bound on the auxiliary one seems to do nothing for us. Ignoring this, I don't understand why it would be $\ll$, considering it seems that the best that Theorem 3.2 would give us could be that it is $O(N^{1/m})$.

If someone could help me here, that'd be great!

Comment: If every trivial solution to the auxiliary equation yields a trivial solution to the original one, then a bound on $r(N)$ for the auxiliary equation yields a bound on $r(N)$ for the original one. (Note that $r(N)$ isn't bounding the number of solutions to an equation, but rather sizes of sets *not* admitting trivial solutions.) Also, $f\ll g$ is "Vinogradov's notation" synonymous with $f=O(g)$.

Comment: @GabeConant Thanks, I clearly just got confused with the definitions there! Also, thanks for clearing up my notation misunderstanding—for some reason I was always under the impression that $f=O(g)$ means either $f\ll g$ or $f\simeq g$.

Comment: I think your impression of the meaning of $f=O(g)$ is probably correct--it's the meaning of $\ll$ that could be off. In particular $f=O(g)$ means $f$ is (eventually) bounded by a constant multiple of $g$, and $f\ll g$ means the same thing (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#History_(Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau,_Hardy,_and_Vinogradov_notations))). The false impression could be that $f\ll g$ means something like $f=o(g)$ (which I agree seems totally reasonable given the look of the notation).

Comment: @GabeConant I see, that makes a lot of sense! Thanks :)